# How to retrieve pandas dataframe from its string representation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The pandas DataFrame object has a to_string() method that is called on the `__repr__` magic method. Thus when I say `x = f'{df}'`, `x` is gonna be the string representation of the dataframe df.

How can I retrieve (reconstruct) the dataframe only having `x`? So I would like a method called `get_dataframe_from_string(df: str) -> pd.DataFrame` that gets the string and returns the dataframe.

The method should be generic, so it should work with multiindices as well.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: An external dependency raises a warning with having the df's string representation in its message. Id like to catch that warning and log that df.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

Use `df.to_csv()` instead of `df.__str__()` and then you can do it.

## str(df) won't work

The short answer is: you can't. At least not with pandas' builtin string representation.

The reason is `df.__repr__` does not have a (mathematical) inverse function:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict(x=range(100), y=range(100)))
print(df)
#      x   y
# 0    0   0
# 1    1   1
# 2    2   2
# 3    3   3
# 4    4   4
# ..  ..  ..
# 95  95  95
# 96  96  96
# 97  97  97
# 98  98  98
# 99  99  99
```

There is no way to know what the rows 5-94 contain.

## A solution: df.to_csv

One could come up with hacks to work around it but the only sensible way to do this Imo is to use well-known pandas methods, e.g. `to_csv`:

```
str_df = df.to_csv()
print(str_df)
# ,x,y
# 0,0,0
# 1,1,1
# 2,2,2
# 3,3,3
```

where `str_df` contains *all the data* (I truncated the output).

Then you can get your original dataframe back using `io` and `read_csv`:

```
import io

original_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(str_df))
print(original_df)
#     Unnamed: 0   x   y
# 0            0   0   0
# 1            1   1   1
# 2            2   2   2
# 3            3   3   3
# 4            4   4   4
# ..         ...  ..  ..
# 95          95  95  95
# 96          96  96  96
# 97          97  97  97
# 98          98  98  98
# 99          99  99  99
```

Note that the column `Unnamed` is the present because we didn't exclude to row names. These can be excluded in `df.to_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` basically does this in its [`read_clipboard`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/clipboards.py#L13) function. It's trying to construct a DataFrame from a string `text`, so you should be able to adopt whatever happens after [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/clipboards.py#L41) line.